# Mysql join table and select when record doesn't exit in left join

Tags: mysql

I have a table which list available items, when user click on any item it will insert in `added_items` table. Now my problem is I want to use join to select all `items` that any user has not added. My current query doesn't show items if one user has added it.

items

```
name   | type | id | user
-------|------|----|------------------
 JAVA  | A    | 1  | SYSTEM
 PHP   | A    | 2  | SYSTEM
 HTML  | B    | 3  | USER1
```

added_items

```
item_id   | user
----------|--------------
1         | peter
```

My query

```
SELECT    it.* 
FROM      items it 
LEFT JOIN added_items ait 
ON        ait.user = it.user 
#on       ait.item_id = it.id 
WHERE     it.type = "A" 
AND       ait.user IS NULL
```

The second query I tried

```
SELECT it.* 
FROM   items it 
       LEFT JOIN added_items ait 
              ON ait.item_id = it.id 
WHERE  it.type = "a" 
       AND ait.user != "peter"
```

Expected result

when current user is `peter` I want to retrieve only `PHP` as `peter` has added `JAVA`.

But if current user isn't on `added_items` the retrieve all record.

Add fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3761e40

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please provide the desired result

Comment: Are you sure that `items.type` column's collation is case-insensitive? try to use `it.type = 'A'`. And do not use dquotes - use it for JSON datatype key/value only.

Comment: *when current user is peter* Where this data must be taken from? MySQL knows nothing about "current user"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM added_items 
                   WHERE items.id = added_items.item_id 
                   -- AND added_items.user = "peter"
                 )
-- AND items.type = 'A'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=881c21fed1b3c76b6b92bf08e757f4f8)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT    it.* 
FROM      items it 
LEFT JOIN added_items ait 
ON        ait.item_id = it.id 
WHERE     ait.item_id IS NULL
```